# Hierarchy of SVN Servers

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Currently all my team members connect to a "CENTRAL SVN server" and they commit their code.
The SVN Server is being used by many other teams.
As such, if one of my team member makes a mistake, it impacts other guys creating a hue and cry :-( .... :-)

What I want to do is to create an "INTERMEDIATE SVN Server" to which all developers will connect to. They commit their code to "INTERMEDIATE SVN Server" and then build/integration testing is done at this "INTERMEDIATE Server". If all tests are OK, then code is further committed from INTERMEDIATE Server to the "CENTRAL SVN Server" thus giving cleaner code to a greater audience.

I know this is basic stuff, but can someone help me realize this by linking me to some documentation/scripts, around this topic. Thanks in anticipation.

I use Tortoise as SVN client.

Regards,
Amol

Comment: I think you want to create an SVN branch for your team (in the same server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over thinking this - you don't need an additional SVN to perform code review before committing to trunk. You would simply create a daily branch (or tag) then merge after review. This is the default way to handle this...

See this link for general help: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html

Branching and Merging: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html

Answer (score 0):

Poorly-planned workflow isn't a reason to do *strange things* (multi-tier for SVN is *such* thing).

Except branching, already mentioned, I can to tell such words, as

- "Continuos Integration",
- "Code Review",
- "Unit- and functional-tests"

You can build chain of SVN-repos, but it's crooked nail and refactoring of business-processes give more. Your question must be not "how to build workaround around stupidness", but "how to do tasks smart"